# Is it correct to use "off" in "I am off to the shops"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

My son says that the use of the word off in a sentence like "I am off to the shops" is incorrect. Is he right?

Comment: Your son has been informed more by grammar books than by English usage.  The expression has  been part of everyday use throughout the English speaking world for a long time. A simple Google search will reveal a large number of instances, both informal and literary. The question, however, is likely to be rejected as more appropriate to our ELL sister site, as a likely duplicate on EL&U, and as insufficiently researched.

Comment: Even apart from *to the shops,* my sense is that "I am off" is more BrE than AmE (and I have also known that phrase to be wickedly and filthily quibbled upon by English lads). Now I find that Ngram suggests it was more BrE than AmE back circa 1950 but is the reverse today.

Comment: @BrianDonovan:  American here, and the expression is entirely familiar and common.  I'm off to see the Wizard.  I'm off to work.  I'm just plain off (oh, wait, that's something different).

Comment: Your kid is just messin' with you.  Take away his allowance and ground him for a week.

Comment: Yeah, certainly "off to see the Wizard" is so incredibly idiomatic as to be trite.

Comment: @deadrat - Don't just ground him, send him off to military school.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed that the usage started off from the Brits, but it is used widely all over now.

You can find a good explanation on its usage in the Oxford dictionary.

" I am off to the shops"  -> This is a perfectly valid and legit statement.

Comment: You should provide a link to this explanation.